# How to concat a number with "Kg" using Jquery. I want to concat the TotalWeight field with unit "Kg"

Tags: javascript

```
**HTML Snippet**

<table id="mytable">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr class="item">
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderQty)
    </td>
    <td class="Weight">
        @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.TotalWeight, new { id="TotalWeight"})
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LimeType.LimeTypeName)
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tr.item").each(function () {
            var weight = $(this).find(td[5].val());
            var unit = "Kg";
            var value = weight + unit;
            $("#TotalWeight").val(value);
        });
          });
</script>
}
 html as in markup
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <tr class="item">
 <td> 1 </td>
 <td> C001 </td>
 <td> 7/26/2013 12:00:00 AM </td>
 <td> 100.00 </td>
 <td class="Weight"> 5000.00 </td>
 <td> Hydrated Lime Powder </td>
 <td> Order Pending </td>
 <td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I want to add Kg to my TotalWeight value.  My code is not working.  It shows the value in
Quantity1 as undefined. How can one access the table in jQuery?
i forgot to define weight, but still the code is not working, i have posted the html markup

Comment: Where is `weight` defined?

Comment: You are missing a </tr> tag, may not be the reason but I'm just pointing out.

Comment: Also it seems you are using the same `totalWeight` id for your elements. **Id attributes should be unique in a HTML page** you can use a class instead but I don't see why it's needed since you put a class on the td already. Also are you using inputs or is the value just a text in the cell?

Comment: Can you provide your actual markup as rendered by the browser?

Comment: Please fix your markup.. it has several invalid entries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr.item").each(function () {
        var weight = $(this).find('td.Weight').text(); // you left out the quotes and the closing paran
        var unit = "Kg";
        $("#TotalWeight").text(weight + unit);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/G23xm/1/)

Comment: I gave the quotes but still it is saying as undefined

Comment: Change `.val()` to `.text()`. TDs do not have values, they only have innerHTML, which can be found using `.text()`.

Comment: @Nasreen Have you fixed this? DO you believe this to be a correct answer now?

Comment: Sir,SORRY for replying so late..You were absolutely correct.The solution worked perfectly for me. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably actually calculate the sum in Scala (it looks you're using Scala) instead. Also your loop closes the `<table>` tag after every model and your `<tr>` tag is never closed. You also have one `ModelItem` that should probably be `modelItem` like in other places.